# Java Generics Question: type parameter E is not within its bound

Tags: java, generics

i've got a question about generics. I have this method which does not compile at all. The compiler tells me: `type parameter E is not within its bound`. I've usually no problem in understanding compiler errors, but this one is quite tricky. Maybe my knowledge about generics need to improve. :-) Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

```
public static <E extends Enum & StringConvertableEnum<E>> Map<String, E> map(Class<E> enumClass) {
    Map<String, E> mapping = new HashMap<String, E>();

    EnumSet<E> set = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass);

    for(E enumConstant : set) {
        mapping.put(enumConstant.getStringValue(), enumConstant);
    }

    return mapping;
}
```

This is the definition of `StringConvertableEnum`:

```
public interface StringConvertableEnum<E extends Enum> {
    public E getEnumFromStringValue(String string);
    public String getStringValue();
}
```

Comment: line number it's complaining at?

Comment: @bmargulies: EnumSet<E> set = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass); is the line.

Comment: I'm out of my depth. Your code looks plausible to me.

Comment: by the way, why would you need to generate such a map? you know that each enum class has a `.valueOf()` static method that allows you to get the enum from its string, right?

Answer (score 9):

You need to change your declaration to `E extends Enum<E>`

Edit, sorry had to step away, the full declaration I mean is:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & StringConvertableEnum<E>> Map<String, E> map(Class<E> enumClass) {
```

Comment: i) This would allow one to pass in enums without the `getStringValue()` method, which is mandatory. ii) it does not compile either, even if i remove the body of the for-loop where the `getStringValue()` method is used.

Comment: @Kraushauslaus: he means change `E extends Enum` to `E extends Enum<E>`: you can keep your `StringConvertableEnum<E>` part.

Comment: @Kraushauslaus I believe @Yishai means insert the `<E>` in both declarations and don't remove anything. Compiles for me.