# Type Parameter is not within its bound

Tags: java, maven, generics, type-parameter

I am getting an error when running maven compile on this class but it seems to work just fine when executing. I have looked a quite a few other posts on the same topic but was unable to get this working for myself.

**EDIT - Removed original code snippets and replaced**

**EDIT - Providing MCVE - very stripped down**

*By the way this is being run on Java 6*

```
public class MainTester {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProtocolHandler<MappingRule> mappingProtocolHandler = new MappingProtocolHandler();

        Map<String, List<MappingRule>> protocols = mappingProtocolHandler.getProtocols();

        System.out.println(protocols);
    }

}
```

ProtocolHandler and Child class:

```
public abstract class ProtocolHandler<E extends Rule<?, ?>> {
    public Map<String, List<E>> getProtocols() {                
            return getProtocolsForRequest();
    }

    protected abstract Map<String, List<E>> getProtocolsForRequest();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class MappingProtocolHandler extends ProtocolHandler<MappingRule>{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, List<MappingRule>> getProtocolsForRequest() {

        return new HashMap<String, List<MappingRule>>();
    }
}
```

Rule Classes:

```
public interface Rule<F, T> {
    public void execute(F object, T object2);
}

public abstract class BaseRule<F, T> implements Rule<F, T>, Comparable<BaseRule<F, T>> {

}

public abstract class MappingRule<F,T> extends BaseRule<F, T> implements CustomAttributes{

}

public abstract class InputRule extends MappingRule<Object, Map<String,Object>> {

}

public abstract class OutputRule extends MappingRule<Map<String, Object>, Object> {

}

public interface CustomAttributes {

}
```

Handler Classes:

```
public abstract class ProtocolHandler<E extends Rule<?, ?>> {
    public Map<String, List<E>> getProtocols() {                
            return getProtocolsForRequest();
    }

    protected abstract Map<String, List<E>> getProtocolsForRequest();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class MappingProtocolHandler extends ProtocolHandler<MappingRule>{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, List<MappingRule>> getProtocolsForRequest() {

        return new HashMap<String, List<MappingRule>>();
    }
}
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project Test: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure: 
>   [ERROR]...\src\main\java\common\main\MainTester.java:[14,18]
>   type parameter common.mapping.rule.MappingRule is not within its bound
>   [ERROR]...\src\main\java\common\handler\MappingProtocolHandler.java:[10,60]
>   type parameter common.mapping.rule.MappingRule is not within its bound

Comment: What is `ProtocolHandler`? Can you show the class declaration that contains that field and method?

Comment: `MappingRule` is a generic type (with parameters), but you are using it _raw_.

Comment: I have added ProtocolHandler to the original post. And cant I use it raw still?

Comment: Show us the class that declares the `mappingProtocolHandler` field.

Comment: original post under edit section, thanks

Comment: I copied your code and I cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: Added a full example above

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: Using both java 1.6 and 1.7 I seem to still get `type argument MappingRule is not within bounds of type-variable E` but it runs just fine and Spring Source Tool Suite doesn't show any compilation errors within the code

Comment: take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775365/java-generics-question-type-parameter-e-is-not-within-its-bound

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use the raw type of `MappingRule`

```
private ProtocolHandler<MappingRule> mappingProtocolHandler;

public void execute(){
 Map<String, List<MappingRule>> protocols =  mappingProtocolHandler.getProtocols(protocolExecutionRequest);
}
```

but

```
private ProtocolHandler<MappingRule<String, String>> mappingProtocolHandler;

public void execute(){
    Map<String, List<MappingRule<String, String>>> protocols = mappingProtocolHandler.getProtocols(/**/);
}
```

EDIT:
if only maven gives you an ERROR, maybe it is configured to treat warnings as errors? see [Javac: Treat warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040074/javac-treat-warnings-as-errors)

EDIT2:
I always get errors when running this code. How do you compile this code? Maybe the eclipse compiler(?) allows you to run this code anyway?

EDIT3:
According to the author of the question, the code runs only in eclipse. Sometimes the eclipse compiler seems to behave differently, but in that case the you should treat the JDK as imperative (since your build is not done in eclipse, but in maven with javac). I am not sure about the reason (one could certainly search the JLS for that), but why mixing type bounds and raw types which were only introduced for backwards compability with Java versions before 1.5?

There seem to be other differences in generics between eclipse and javac: [Maven Compiler vs Eclipse Compiler Generics Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823705/maven-compiler-vs-eclipse-compiler-generics-difference)

Comment: I was attempting to only have to define one ProtocolHandler vs one for each Type of MappingRule

Comment: Well `MappingRule` is a generic type, so some type information should be provided, I have updated my post, for example with `<String,String>`

Comment: I understand its a generic but aren't you able to use them as rawtypes such as with `List testList = new ArrayList();` that is generic and gives you warnings but is still okay to use in most contexts

Comment: just within eclipse it automatically builds and allows me to use it without an issues